# Interpretation with training and test set with standardized variables

Tags: interpretation, standardization, generalized-additive-model, regression-strategies

I've standardized all the variables (even the response variable) and then I've split my data into a training and test part.  And for example, I've got the following model based on my TRAINING set:
y = 0.5x_1 - 0.2x_2

Now I shall get values for y like -0.4,0.7,... but I want to say something about the original response variable. What can I do to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated elsewhere on this site, standardization gets in the way of understanding.  Your example is a particularly good case of this.  Re-do with no standardization.  Besides problems of interpretation, your method completely breaks down if the standard deviations of $x$ and $y$ are not the same in the two samples.

Comment: For my project, we have to give a prediction model. I have to compare models so I've standardized it at the beginning (because this is important for methods like KNN). But now, I can't make a good prediction because it's standardized. What should you do: 1) Discuss the model with the standardized variables or 2) For the method that I've chosen recalculate everything (but then I've become a slightly different model wrt terms and coefficient).

Comment: A good predictive method should not require standardization.  But if it really does, you will need to un-standardize the model or write down the exact translations (using means and SDs) that pre-transform the variables so you can apply those exact same constants in evaluating on the test sample.  And what is the size of your training sample and your test sample?  It would need to be many thousands for split-sample validation to work.

Comment: My training sample is 2400 and my test sample is 1200. Is that enough?

Comment: No, unless your signal:noise ratio is very large (high inherent $R^2$).

Comment: Oo, pity :( And would you advise me to do know? Do everything again but without standardisation?

Comment: Model validation is best done in my experience using the Efron-Gong "optimism" bootstrap as implemented in the R `rms` package.  This takes for example 400 resamples (400 model fits and evaluations).  Or you can do 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation.  The problem with data splitting is that you split again and get significantly different results.  Note that if you started with two terms in the model and ended with two terms, there is very little to overfit and so little need to validate [but then you wouldn't be using knn].